# htaccess file for codeigniter on subdomain virtualhost

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess, subdomain, virtualhost

i have problem about .htaccess file for my codeigniter installation.
On localhost this work fine, when i upload online its rewrite URL but the website not work.

this is my htaccess on localhost:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /jCore_01/
#RewriteBase /

### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]



# Enforce NO www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

online i have a problem:
i put this file on subdomain jcore.miodomio.com and it rewrite URL but not work

example:
without htaccess it's work:
jcore.miodominio.com/index.php/en/home

with htaccess
jcore.miodominio.com/en/home

Not Found

The requested URL /en/home was not found on this server.

can anyone help me? suggestion? 
regards

Denny

Answer (score 1):

Try change your htaccess to:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]`

Comment: sorry, i dont write that i just removed it

Comment: in application/config/config.php in line 14
$config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: can u send the subdomain which have the problem so that i can help.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: try this htaccess . if it work may i see what in your htacess

Answer (score 0):

Somethings to consider.

1. Did you enable Apache rewrite module?
2. If enabled check whether your virtual host file is configured properly So to make sure its hitting .htaccess or try putting some dump on .htacess , So if its hitting .htaccess than you should get an 500 server error.

If you are not getting error than its mostly the problem in your host settings.